# Dream holiday poll

Tags: python

Now ALL of the below works as intended - a poll asks users questions and I store them in a dictionary, finally I print how many times a country was mentioned - boring I know. However, I really want to know if there is **better, cleaner even high level way** to do this (*reading comments here people usually mention speed, efficiency always gets me excited and motivated to carry on learning*) and if I am falling into any potholes or bad practices. I am not new to programming but new to Python, I would genuinely appreciate the help. Stay safe :)

```
dream_vacation_poll = {}
question = 'What is your dream holiday? '

while True:
   name = input('Name: ').lower()
   message = input(question).lower()
   dream_vacation_poll[name] = message
   message = input('Does anyone else want to answer? (y/n)').lower()
   if message == 'n':
      break
   else:
      continue

results = {}
for country in dream_vacation_poll.values():
   count = 0
   v = country
      for value in dream_vacation_poll.values():
        if v == value:
          count += 1
          results[v] = count

print(results)
```

Comment: The second block (with the two `for` loops) could be refactored to a **list comprehension** in order to produce more compact and Pythonic code.

Comment: There is no way that this code can run. Please can you update your question with working code. Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, the indentation starting at `for value` is broken. This is required to be fixed for Python to be able to interpret it.

Comment: Said another way: if you copy the code out of this question and paste it into your IDE, are you _sure_ that this works as intended?

Comment: `efficiency always gets me excited` there's (computing) machinery resources, and other. Such as *human*, including *user*s and *developer*s.

Comment: @Reinderien apologies for the indentation issue, code does work I just messed up when I copied and pasted here.

Comment: @greybeard I’m sorry I don’t follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a few issues with this code, which can be easily fixed.

The first is really small. In your `while True` loop you read the name of a person and then apply `.lower()` to it. I'd consider using `.title()`, because it makes first letter capital. Example:

```
>>> 'nIKOlay'.title()
'Nikolay'
```

I'm not really sure if you should also use `.title()` with dream vacation message, because dream vacation is not necessary a country/city.

You also don't need that `else: continue` block in 'while True', because it basically does nothing in your program. So it's better to just remove it.

The third issue is pretty major, as I think. There's a much simpler way to get the `results` dictionary. You can do this right in your `while True` loop when you read the `message`. So the code will be:

```
dream_vacation_poll = {}
results = {}
question = 'What is your dream holiday? '

while True:
    name = input('Name: ').title()
    message = input(question).lower()
    dream_vacation_poll[name] = message

    if message in results.keys():
        results[message] += 1
    else:
        results[message] = 1

    message = input('Does anyone else want to answer? (y/n)').lower()
    if message == 'n':
        break

print(results)
```

But there's an even more elegant solution. Instead of checking if the key is in `results.keys()` we can use `defaultdict` from collections module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dream_vacation_poll = {}
# create defaultdict and set all values equal to 0 by default
# we use this so we dont have to check if key is in results.keys()
results = defaultdict(int)
question = 'What is your dream holiday? '

while True:
    name = input('Name: ').lower()
    message = input(question).lower()
    dream_vacation_poll[name] = message

    results[message] += 1

    message = input('Does anyone else want to answer? (y/n)').lower()
    if message == 'n':
        break

# convert defaultdict to dict
print(dict(results))
```

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation learnt  something new today (deafultdict) , always appreciate people like you thanks again. Also realised I need to really narrow down what I want each part of my program to do, that way my logic can improve. Do you have any techniques for this or is it just experience ?